# How can I turn off Windows 7 Update restart reminders if I have Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

This popup appears after Windows updates have been (partially) installed:

[image]

It is incessantly annoying and I'd like to prevent it form appearing. There are plenty of articles that recommend disabling it using `gpedit`, but I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium and `gpedit` does not exist on that version.

I've used a registry modification to disable the computer from actually restarting on it's own (usually there is a countdown timer), but the above popup remains. I just want Windows to install important updates and leave me alone until I decide to restart on my own time.

I don't want to turn off Windows Update, so is there any other means of turning this reminder off?

Comment: So you want it to just reboot unconditionally without any warning?

Comment: @martineau No, sorry I had forgot to mention that I had [disabled automatic restarts](http://blog.laptopmag.com/disable-automatic-restart-windows), but the popup persists.

Comment: Although there may be a registry tweak to disable this, I would suggest configuring updates to _not_ automatically download and install them -- because that's what's creating the issue. Set it to just display a notification when updates are available.

Comment: @Moses - Just configure your computer to only install updates when you manually run `Windows Update`.  You could upgrade to Windows 8 the update behavior changed significantly.  Microsoft realized that if your using your computer the installation of the update could wait.  It will wait up to 2 days before presenting a similar prompt.

Comment: I guess I would just prefer Windows to install important updates automatically, and and not bother me about restarting until I actually do it myself.